# Como usar ajax dentro de um SweetAlert?

Tags: javascript, ajax, sweetalert

Tentei assim, mas acredito que não seja a forma correta. Na verdade tenho certeza, pois o código não funciona.

```
function removeCliente(id)
  {

   swal({
   title: "Are you sure?",
   text: "You will not be able to recover this imaginary file!",
   type: "warning",
   showCancelButton: true,
   confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
   confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
   cancelButtonText: "No, cancel plx!",
   closeOnConfirm: false,
   closeOnCancel: false
      },
    function(isConfirm){
       if (isConfirm) {
             {function(id)
                $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:'removeClientes.php',
            data: {
                'idexclusao': id

            });
             },
            swal("Deleted!",
             "Your imaginary file has been deleted.", "success");

             window.location.href = 'clientes.php';   
        } 
        else 
        { 
            swal("Cancelled", "Your imaginary file is safe :)", "error");   
        } 
    });

   }
```

Comment: Não sei se esse é o problema, mas me parece que no trecho `if (isConfirm) { {function(id)` existe um erro de sintaxe. Talvez possa ser isso

Comment: Retornou algum erro no console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não sei exatamente como funciona esse sweetalert, mas reescrevi a função corrigindo alguns erros de sintaxe e mudando um pouco o ajax pra ter um callback de sucesso ou falha:

```
function(isConfirm){
       if (isConfirm) {

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url:'removeClientes.php',
                data: ({'idexclusao': id})
            }).done(function(data) {
                swal("Deleted!", "Your imaginary file has been deleted.", "success");
                window.location.href = 'clientes.php';
            }).fail(function(data) {
                //código em caso de erro
                swal("Cancelled", "Your imaginary file is with some problem :(", "error");   
            });

        } 
        else 
        { 
            swal("Cancelled", "Your imaginary file is safe :)", "error");   
        } 
}
```

Espero ter ajudado, até.

Comment: Valeu luis, realmente era erro de sintaxe :)